# How to find which column corresponds to a constraint?

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2008 for a web application.

I have a table which has constraints on a few columns. When running the web application, I got a database error:

> Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ__Customer__DDDFDD3762E4AA3C'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Customer'. The duplicate key value is (<NULL>)

I have a gut feeling which column causes this problem.

However, is there any way within Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio that I can use to pinpoint the column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click the table, then choose `Script table as` -> `Create to` -> `New query editor window`.  That will list all the constraints on the table with their names.

Alternatively, click `+` next to the table, then `+` next to Constraints.  Your constraint should be listed there.  You can double click to edit it, or script it like described for the table above.

Comment: Thanks for chiming in. The constraint that causes the problem is a Unique Key constraint, not displayed in your "Script table as -> Create to -> New query editor window", in which only FK keys are listed. When I click + next to Constraints, it is blank.

Comment: Right, a unique constraint is listed as a unique index instead.  Check `+ Indexes` below the table.  Check out `Tools -> Options -> SQL Server Object Explorer -> Scripting` and then `Table and view options` to choose what will be scripted along with the table.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE
where CONSTRAINT_NAME = '.....'
```

EDIT:

If constraint doesn't appear in `information_schema`, you may try to look for it in sys* tables:

```
select c.name as [column], t.name as [table] 
from sysobjects o 
    inner join syscolumns c on o.id = c.cdefault
    inner join sysobjects t on c.id = t.id
where o.name = 'UQ....'
```

Comment: I tried "select * from
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE
where CONSTRAINT_NAME like 'UQ%'" and the constraint mentioned above does not show up. I do see other UQ constraints

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. It will give you a list of all unique constraints

```
SELECT TC.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG as [Database],
TC.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA as [Schema],
TC.TABLE_NAME as [Table],
CCU.COLUMN_NAME as [Column]
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS TC
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE CCU on TC.CONSTRAINT_NAME = CCU.CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE TC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'UNIQUE'
```